# WSL 2: VS Code´s npm scritps doen´t refresh when creating a new script in package.json

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I write a new script in package.json the **npm scripts** view doesn´t refresh with the new script. I have to restart VS Code to see the new script in it.

Also, when I create a new file into the folder via terminal, the folder´s view doesn´t refresh automatically. I have to click into refresh button to see the new files.

I´m running VS Code with WLS extension and my project is located at windows C: filesystem (/mnt/c/Users/paulo/src).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your project to inside WLS file system (e.g /home/pauloh/src).

It solves VS Code refresh issues and is recommended for better perfomance.